# Help with Hartree-Fock integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate an effective potential function for a particle in a box which takes into account the repulsion between two electrons. 
The integral is

```
Integrate[E^(x2 - 1)^2 1/(x1 - x2) E^(x2 - 1)^2, {x2, 0, 2}]
```

and I keep getting the integral returned again with no answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What answer do you expect to get?  Is x1 in (0,2)?  Any particular reason you are you writing the exponential twice, rather than just `E^(2 (x2-1)^2)`?

Comment: No particular reason, it was just how I wrote it. x1 should be between 0 and 2 because it is the position of a particle on a distance between 0 and 2.

Comment: Are there any constraints on x1?

Comment: @jim what prevents this integral from blowing up when `x2 == x1`?

Comment: @bill yes it is contrained to be between 0 and 2 as well

Comment: If you add the assumption: `Integrate[E^(x2 - 1)^2 1/(x1 - x2) E^(x2 - 1)^2, {x2, 0, 2},  Assumptions -> 0 < x1 < 2]` then you get the message that the integral does not converge on {0,2}.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 6):

Would a numeric approach be sufficient?

```
hf[x1_?NumericQ] := 
  E^(2 x1^2) (Log[(x1 + 1)/(1 - x1)]) + 
   NIntegrate[(E^(2 x2^2) - E^(2 x1^2))/(x1 - x2), {x2, -1, 1}];

Plot[hf[x1], {x1, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here I made a few transformations. I translated the problem from the interval `{0, 2}` to `{-1, 1}`, which made it easier for me to read (especially the symmetry). I also cleaved the singular part off and assumed that the Cauchy Principal Value was sought.

```
E^(2 x2^2)/(x1 - x2) == E^(2 x1^2)/(x1 - x2) + (E^(2 x2^2) - E^(2 x1^2))/(x1 - x2)
```

The integral of the first term is

```
Integrate[E^(2 x1^2)/(x1 - x2), {x2, -1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> -1 < x1 < 1, PrincipalValue -> True]
(*  E^(2 x1^2) Log[(1 + x1)/(1 - x1)]  *)
```

---

Alternatively, one can integrate a series expansion of the second term to get a rapidly convergent series approximation to the integral.

```
ClearAll[integral, integralterm, hf2];

(* integral of a term of the power series *)
integralterm[x1_ /; x1 == 0, k_] := x1; 
integralterm[x1_, k_] = 
 Block[{x1, x2, 
   k}, -(2^k/k!) x1^(2 k - 1)
        Sum[(x1 (x2/x1)^(j + 1))/(
        j + 1), {j, 0, 2 k - 1}] /. {{x2 -> -1}, {x2 -> 1}} // 
     Differences // First // FullSimplify[#, -1 < x1 < 1] &
  ];

(* sum of the integrals of the terms up to order n *)
integral[x_, n_] := Total@Table[integralterm[x, k], {k, n}];

(* the total integral, approximated with n terms of the series *)
hf2[x1_ /; x1 == 0, n_] := x1;
hf2[x1_] := hf2[x1, 24];      (* order 24 gives ~MachinePrecision, less rounding error *)
hf2[x1_, n_Integer] :=
  (hf2[x_, n] = Block[{x}, -E^(2 x^2) Log[(1 - x)/(1 + x)] + integral[x, n]];
   hf2[x1, n]);
```

It's faster and arbitrary accuracy is possible by including more terms.

```
Plot[hf2[x1], {x1, -1, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[hf[x1], {x1, -1, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Machine precision begins to be obtained around `n == 20`. The convergence at the ends of the interval is of course slower. At `n == 24`, convergence stops improving (using machine precision inputs) because of rounding error.  I use a high-precision version of the `NIntegrate` method above for checking the accuracy of the series expansion.

```
hf[x_?NumericQ, wp_] :=(* high precision *)
  With[{x1 = SetPrecision[x, wp + 0.5]},
   E^(2 x1^2) (Log[(x1 + 1)/(1 - x1)]) + 
    NIntegrate[(E^(2 x2^2) - E^(2 x1^2))/(x1 - x2), {x2, -1, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> wp]]

ListPlot[Transpose@Table[
   RealExponent@{(#1 - #2)/#2, #1 - #2} &[hf2[x1, 24], hf[x1, 32]],
   {x1, Range[-1., 1., 1./1024][[2 ;; -2 ;; 2]]}],
 PlotRange -> {-17., -13.}, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> {None, {RealExponent@$MachineEpsilon}}, 
 DataRange -> {-1, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x1, HoldForm[Log10[error]]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>
> A plot of the relative error (blue) and absolute error (yellow).